# Dynamically Update Width of Float Left Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked through a variety of other posts, and to no avail, I have yet to find the kind of solution I'm looking for. Many solutions involved people using CSS with methods like fixing the right and left (which wouldn't make it worth floating and a waste of brain power) or to word-wrap at a certain amount to the right (which also defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do.

My problem exists like this:
I have 3 divs: wrapper, menu, and content. Wrapper is used to apply a background to 100% of the page, and create extra styling properties to be inherited by other CSS. Menu is for my menu script I coded in JQuery and it takes up 400px of space on the left hand of the screen and descends downwards at 100vh. I may change it to fixed, but it doesn't change the issue. Anyway, content is the rest of the page; let's say the other 80% of it. I have both menu and content floating left and it works just fine. However, until text wraps at the end of the screen, the div goes under (disappears in my case) the screen and no longer viewable.

My solution:

```
function simplyWidth(changed, menu1, wrapper){
    var wrapperWidth = $(wrapper).width();
    var menuWidth = $(menu1).width();
    var newWidth = wrapperWidth - menuWidth;

    $(changed).css("width", newWidth);

};
```

Does it work? Of course it works. The only problem is, it isn't dynamic at all! It resizes to the screen once, and you have to refresh the page just to get it to update again. Is there a way to take that JQuery/Javascript and make it so I can just update it every .1 of a second? Would that make the page lag? Or am I doing it wrong.

Also assume that my HTML is spot on, and it needs no corrections. The reason I won't disclose it is because there's too much there for me to post and to not confuse the living crap out of you people.

This is the basic layout of my page:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="menu1"></div>
<div id="content"></div>

</div>
```

As for my wrapper CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image:url(Assets/background1.jpg);
}
```

Menu1 CSS:

```
#menu1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    background-color:#191919;
    color:white;
    z-index: 400;
    float: left;

}
```

Content CSS:

```
#content {
    float:left;
    color:white;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: `$(window).resize()`? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

listen to resize event and call the same function when the window is resized:

```
$(window).resize(simplyWidth);
```

Comment: Thank you, it didn't work right out of the gate because I was confused as to why nothing showed up. I stopped to think for a moment and realized it was because the script was waiting for the browser to change size before it would actually set the width of #content. My update code looks like this now:

`simplyWidth('#content','#menu1','#wrapper');
 $(window).resize(function(){simplyWidth('#content','#menu1','#wrapper')});`

Thank you for the help.